# Regex: Confused about the $ operator

Tags: regex

So I'm just messing around the internet and found this **regex** w/c is quite interesting.
I'm very new to this stuff and I wanted to done this search pattern tonight. However, I'm quite confused in the `$` operator. And I'm running out of terms what keywords should I search on Google.

Regex:

```
(?<=<RGBA?:(-?\d{1,3},?){3,4}>).*(?=</RGBA?>$)
```

Data:

```
<RGBA:255,255,255,2>HEY</RGBA>
<RGB:-1,-25,-3>Is this a typo?</RGB>
<RGB:255,255,255>YOH</RGB>
<RGB:0,1,2>Please let me go here :(</RGB>
<RGBA:0,255,12,255>o my, what to do here?!!!!</RGBA>
hahahah
hehehe2123
<RGB:-0,-0,-0>GET ME</RGB>
```

This will only get the last line `GET ME`, but if I remove the `$` the result is as expected but fails if the `string` is contiguous (no newline).For example:

Data:

```
<RGBA:255,255,255,2>HEY</RGBA> <RGB:-1,-25,-3>Is this a typo?</RGB>
```

Returns:

```
HEY</RGBA> <RGB:-1,-25,-3>Is this a typo?
```

Please explain so I can resolve this.

PS. *The data(string) format is for another application I made*

Comment: `$` (and `.`) are interpreted differently by different programs/languages.  What are you using?  sed?  Perl?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't know but I do this online [here](http://www.softlion.com/webTools/RegExpTest/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is something like this:

```
(?<=<RGBA?:(-?\d{1,3},?){3,4}>).*?(?=</RGBA?>)
```

The ? after the .* makes the expression lazy instead of greedy, so it won't match past the closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

`$` specifies that end of the input must match the pattern. for instance, the regex

```
foo$
```

would match

```
myfoo
```

but not

```
foobar
```

`^` specifies that the beginning of the input must match the pattern. So if you had the regex

```
^foo
```

it would match

```
foobar
```

but not

```
myfoo
```

if you combined both, eg

```
^foo$
```

it would match only the pattern

```
foo
```

all other input would fail.

Comment: Note that commonly, multiline text input is matched line by line, and then `^` and `$` mean start and end of line.

Comment: which "it"? Examples above work on the link to the tester you posted.

Comment: it=multiline text. "commonly" means for example `grep`.

Comment: I tried all of possible combinations I could think of, even grouping each `open and close tags` (*of the data to be analyzed in the regex*), grouped the whole "regex", and enabling/disabling `multi-line` options but it won't work in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the `$` operator matches the end of the input. So for example

```
[0-9]+$
```

would match one or more digits, but they must appear at the end of the string.

Edit: After following your link in the comments, the `$` operator does match the end of the input string, which explains why when you keep it in, you only get the last match.

Comment: But how would I tell if the `end tag` of the string I'm looking for is reached and should be popped out of the string and push to the stack of the returned values, but definitely not in the end of the string I'm searching with.

Comment: For that I don't know. I thought you were not sure about the meaning of the `$` operator. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: No its okay. Its just not clear in my post what's my point. Anyway, thanks for answering :)

Comment: No problem. I hope you figure out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, `$` matches the end of the entire input string by default. But in many languages, the meaning can be altered with an option called something like 'multi-line'. Then the `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each **line**, respectively.

Comment: Yes, I'm enabling and disabling those but still no luck :(